# Best way to store visits statistics with cache

Tags: php, caching

What is the best way to store statistics for a threads with caching?

What I actually need is to store how many visits are daily on the difference threads on my community.

But it so the cache is secured and it should be possible to later put it into the database.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "But it so the cache is secured..."?

The simplest way would be to use a mySQL Database. It's simple to use and secure. If you don't have a database, you could also store the visits/views in a plain text file or multiple text based files.

Comment: I need somehow make the cache files secure, that was what I meant. Sorry. Im tired.

Comment: Store the files in a directory that is not accessible from outside. Or  just use an .htaccess file to secure the directory. You will still be able to access the files within your php code using i/o functions such as fopen.